# No broker/node available in test with Kafka in TestContainers

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I am trying to create a bare-bones skeleton integration test for Kafka with TestContainers: just publish message to topic and check it arrives to it (entire setup below).

`SkeletonTests.kt`

```kotlin
@Testcontainers
class SkeletonTests {
  @Container
  private val kafka = KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"))

  @Test
  fun `do nothing special`() {
    // Arrange
    val producer = KafkaProducer(
      mapOf(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to kafka.bootstrapServers),
      StringSerializer(),
      StringSerializer()
    )

    val consumer = KafkaConsumer(
      mapOf(
        ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to kafka.bootstrapServers,
        ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to 1,
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to "earliest",
        ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG to "test-group-id"
      ),
      StringDeserializer(),
      StringDeserializer()
    ).apply { subscribe(listOf("topic")) }

    // Act
    producer.send(ProducerRecord("topic", "Hello there!"))
    producer.flush()

    // Assert
    assertEquals(consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).first().value(), "Hello there!")
  }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.11")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:kafka:1.17.1")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.17.1")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}
```

`logback.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Test passes (`ProducerTests > do nothing special() PASSED`) however log is flooded with producer and consumer warnings. Is this expected? Am I missing some configuration for broker/leader to make this errors go away?

Producer:

```
02:12:11.204 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
02:12:11.255 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node localhost:61785 (id: 1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
02:12:11.255 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:61785 (id: 1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
02:12:11.255 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:328)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
02:12:11.256 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node 1 disconnected.
02:12:11.256 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:61785) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

02:14:39.670 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

02:14:39.670 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Requesting metadata update for topic topic due to error LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Consumer:

```
02:21:11.351 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Initiating connection to node localhost:61785 (id: 1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
02:21:11.352 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1374)
02:21:11.352 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Node 1 disconnected.
02:21:11.352 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:61785) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
02:21:11.353 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] No broker available to send FindCoordinator request

02:21:11.543 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] No broker available to send FindCoordinator request
02:21:11.543 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
02:21:11.544 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Sending FindCoordinator request to broker localhost:61785 (id: 1 rack: null)
02:21:11.544 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Initiating connection to node localhost:61785 (id: 1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
02:21:11.545 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:306)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1374)
02:21:11.545 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Node 1 disconnected.
02:21:11.545 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:61785) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
02:21:11.545 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] Cancelled request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=4, clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, correlationId=14) due to node 1 being disconnected
02:21:11.545 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-group-id] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-test-group-id-1, groupId=test-group-id] FindCoordinator request failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

Update: I removed Spring dependencies completely however the problem persists and that suggests I am misconfiguring TestContainers.

Comment: Your producer test passed because you never flush the producer buffer to actually send data to the broker. Also, the producer and consumer are using different ports based on the logs you posted? That shouldn't happen

Comment: I have added explicit template.flush() after sending message in test - still passes. You are right, ports of producer and consumer are the same - I used logs from two different runs in the answer (updated the question)

Comment: Unrelated to your Kafka logs, but you don't need to use the Testcontainers JUpiter extension here (with `@Testcontainers` and `@Container`), since you are starting the container by hand in your `init` block.